# Getting the global coordinate of a Node in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

How can I get the actual position of a node **in the scene**. The absolute position, regardless of any containers/transforms.

For example, I want to translate a certain node `a` so that it would temporarily overlap another node `b`. So I wish to set his `translateX` property to `b.globalX-a.globalX`.

The documentation says:

> Defines the X coordinate of the
>   translation that is added to the
>   transformed coordinates of this Node
>   for the purpose of layout. Containers
>   or Groups performing layout will set
>   this variable relative to
>   layoutBounds.minX in order to position
>   the node at the desired layout
>   location.
>
> For example, if child should have a
>   final location of finalX:

```
 child.layoutX = finalX - child.layoutBounds.minX;
```

That is, the final coordinates of any node should be

```
finalX = node.layoutX + node.layoutBounds.minX
```

However running the following code:

```
var rect;
Stage {
    title: "Application title"
    width: 250
    height:250
    scene: Scene {
        content: [
            Stack{content:[rect = Rectangle { width:10 height:10}] layoutX:10}
        ]
    }
}

println("finalX = {rect.layoutX+rect.layoutBounds.minX}");
```

gives me `finalX = 0.0` instead of `finalX = 10.0` as the docs seemingly state.

Is there a clear method to get the absolutely final positioning coordinates in JavaFX?

Comment: Just wondering, what format is the code above in? It isn't Java, maybe JSON?

Comment: It's JavaFX, a new programming language from Sun/Oracle.

Comment: The format, I know it's JavaFX, but it isn't Java code.

Comment: @chris13524 JavaFX had it's own format back in the JavaFX 1.x days.

Comment: JavaFX is not a "programming language" - its a **framework** for / within Java ... Oracle ships it with every JRE and JDK, no additional packaging needed (anymore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only solution I found so far is

```
rect.localToScene(rect.layoutBounds.minX, rect.layoutBounds.minY) // a Point2D{x:Float y:Float} object
```

Which doesn't seem to me as the "best" way to do that (note that this function is not bound). Still it works for JavaFX 1.2.

Answer (score 14):

For bounds:

```
bounds = rect.localToScene(rect.getBoundsInLocal());
```

Work for JavaFx 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

Since JavaFX 8, there are additional methods converting local coordinates to screen coordinates. Their names start with "localToScreen"

You can check following link
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScreen-double-double-