# Get screen coordinates of a node in javaFX 8

Tags: java, javafx, awt, javafx-8, awtrobot

I am developing a JavaFX application on Windows 8.1 64bit with 4GB of RAM with JDK version 8u45 64bit.

I want to capture part of the screen using `Robot` but the problem is that I can't get the screen coordinates of the anchor pane that I want to capture and I don't want to use `snapshot` because the output quality is bad. Here is my code.

I have seen the question in this link
[Getting the global coordinate of a Node in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531538/getting-the-global-coordinate-of-a-node-in-javafx)
and this one
[get real position of a node in javaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148690/get-real-position-of-a-node-in-javafx)
and I tried every answer but nothing is working, the image shows different parts of the screen.

```
private void capturePane() {
    try {
        Bounds bounds = pane.getLayoutBounds();
        Point2D coordinates = pane.localToScene(bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY());
        int X = (int) coordinates.getX();
        int Y = (int) coordinates.getY();
        int width = (int) pane.getWidth();
        int height = (int) pane.getHeight();
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(X, Y, width, height);
        BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        ImageIO.write(capture, "png", new File("image.png"));
    } catch (IOException | AWTException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: In what regard is the "output quality" of snapshot bad?

Comment: Sometimes the image isn't sharp.

Comment: have you tried localToScreen()Because local to scene wiill return coordinates within scene which when you put into robot will capture different location

Comment: @TomasBisciak I just tried localToScreen() and the image showed the corner of the screen even further

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you are starting with local (not layout) coordinates, use `getBoundsInLocal()` instead of `getLayoutBounds()`. And since you are wanting to transform to screen (not scene) coordinates, use `localToScreen(...)` instead of `localToScene(...)`:

```
private void capturePane() {
    try {
        Bounds bounds = pane.getBoundsInLocal();
        Bounds screenBounds = pane.localToScreen(bounds);
        int x = (int) screenBounds.getMinX();
        int y = (int) screenBounds.getMinY();
        int width = (int) screenBounds.getWidth();
        int height = (int) screenBounds.getHeight();
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        ImageIO.write(capture, "png", new File("image.png"));
    } catch (IOException | AWTException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```